# Html img tag alt message overlaps the particular div width when image is not displaying in IE8?

Tags: html, css

Please Can anybody help me.

Actually my problem is in IE8  image tag alt message getting overlaps the particular div   width.

My code is:

```
<div class="user-avatar left push-right-px10">
        <img    alt='event photo' title='' src='event image'>
      </div>
```

When event image not getting alt message overlaps the div width.But it's not done.

venki.
 Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Be consistent, use double quotes/single quotes. Not both - just an advice. And Please create fiddle with more code.

Comment: Please describe your problem in directly observable terms. “Overlaps the div width” does not do that. How would you describe the issue to someone who does not know HTML and CSS at all? Also check whether the problem can be observed using the exact code you posted and nothing else. If it can, remove the `class` attribute, since as such it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the issue, but it sounds like the error-box and alt text overflow the container rather than wrapping. Is that right?

If so, two possible solutions are:

1. Declare the `width` or `max-width` of the image so the alternate text stays in the bounds you set.
2. Set the parent `<div>` to `overflow:hidden;` so that even if the alt text overflows, it will no be shown outside the edge of the container.

Hope that helps!